# Is it possible to define side-euclidean divisions in square matrices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Is it always possible to find square matrices $Q, Q', R, R'$ and a map $\phi : M_{n\times n}(K)\to\Bbb N$ such that $A=BQ+R$, $A=Q'B+R'$ and $\phi(R), \phi(R')$ are smaller than $\phi(B)$? Multiplication is not commutative, so we should consider "left euclidean divisions" and "right euclidean divisions".

Comment: What does "$R$, $R'$ smaller than $B$ in an interesting sense" mean?

Comment: I can't possibly know, in natural numbers we use modulus and in polynomials we use degrees, as an example. My question is whether there is a natural extension of this process in matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search yielded [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-45/issue-1/Left-Euclidean-rings/pjm/1102947704.full). I did not find this paper particularly clear, partly because I have never seen transfinite induction before, but it was the best that I could find.

In the first half they define $\phi:R_{n\times n} \to \mathbb{N}$ with $R_{n\times n}$ being the $n\times n$-Matrices over a left euclidean ring by $\phi(A) := n + 1 - rank(A)$ for $A \ne 0$ and $\phi(0) = 0$ and prove that this gives a left euclidean ring, i.e. for every $A, B\in R_{n\times n}$ there are $Q, R \in R_{n\times n}$ such that $A = QB + R$ and $\phi(R) < \phi(B)$, i.e. $rank(R) > rank(B)$ or $R=0$.

I personally cannot explain why this would be a reduction of $A$, because the rank of the remainder actually increases. On the other hand the fact that $R_{n\times n}$ is a left euclidean domain ought to be useful for ring theory.